# PDFTron imported base64 signature is low quality

Tags: pdftron

I am exporting typed and image signatures using `exportSignatures()`, wherein I get a String value similar to the following for each one:

```
[
  "data:image/png;base64,qwerty...",
  "data:image/png;base64,asdfgh..."
]
```

Whenever I try to load typed and image upload signatures back using `importSignatures(signatureArray)`, the imported signatures are of much lower quality, and have a slight transparency on the entire image.

Is there a setting in the `importSignatures` to make it use the original quality?

- If I try to parse and load only the actual base64 content (`qwerty` or `asdfgh`), it doesn't work.
- But if I also try to decode just the base64 using an external decoder I am able to get the original quality of the image.

Here is a sample image of the original (left) and exported-imported (right) signatures:

[image: PDFTron Signature Quality]

The code I used to export/import the signatures are similar to the samples in the official documentation:

```
const signatureTool = docViewer.getTool('AnnotationCreateSignature');
const signatures = signatureTool.exportSignatures();
// save signatures to database as string array

// get signatures from database as string array
const signatureTool = docViewer.getTool('AnnotationCreateSignature');
signatureTool.importSignatures(signatures);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to share the code snippet on how to reproduce this? Or would you be able to share a screenshot of the resulted signature? We haven't had such an issue reported before.

Comment: I have edited my question above to include a screenshot as well as some code (which was based off the documentation anyways).

Comment: Hello, apologize for the delay, would you be able to give the try to a new 7.3 version of WebViewer? You can download it here https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/download/web/